# How to make global function in nodejs expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a function to make capitalize every first word in nodejs expressjs like this:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
        // You do not need to check if i is larger than splitStr length, as your for does that for you
        // Assign it back to the array
        splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);     
    }
    // Directly return the joined string
    return splitStr.join(' '); 
  }
```

But how can i use that function in global? So i can use that in my controller.

I have tried to make function.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  titleCase: function(str) {
    var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
        // You do not need to check if i is larger than splitStr length, as your for does that for you
        // Assign it back to the array
        splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);     
    }
    // Directly return the joined string
    return splitStr.join(' '); 
  } 
}
```

and require function.js file in server.js like this:

```
require('./app/helpers/function');
```

But its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, just make sure the syntax is right.

**If you don't know the difference between these two things below or when to use them, you should read about it.**

- Simplest way:

```js
exports.titleCase = function(str) {
    // function here
}
```

- `Module.exports` way:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    // function here
}
module.export = {
    titleCase,
}
```

And require for both:

```js
// Require
const {titleCase} =  require('./app/helpers/function');
// => titleCase("something");
// or
const func =  require('./app/helpers/function');
// => func.titleCase("something")
```

Comment: Thanks its work, but the require cant i add to server.js file?

Comment: Could you repeat the problem in another way?

Answer (score 1):

```
global['titleCase'] = require('./app/helpers/function');
```

please update your server.js with global['titleCase'] = require('./app/helpers/function'); instead of require('./app/helpers/function');

Comment: please update your server.js with global['titleCase'] = require('./app/helpers/function'); instead of require('./app/helpers/function');

Comment: Write that comment directly into the answer, please. You can edit it.